# pandas to numpy array for sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, converters, pipeline

I have a transformer which calculates the percentage of the values per group. Initially, pandas was used because I started with pandas and colnames are nicer to handle. However, now I need to integrate into sklearn-pipeline.

How can I **convert my Transformer to support numpy** arrays from a sklearn **pipeline** instead of pandas data frames?
The point is that `self.colname` cant be used for numpy arrays and I think the grouping needs to be performed differently.

How to implement **persistence** of such a transformer as these *weights* need to be loadable from disk in order to deploy such a Transformer in a pipeline.

```
class PercentageTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, colname,typePercentage='totalTarget', _target='TARGET', _dropOriginal=True):
        self.colname = colname
        self._target = _target
        self._dropOriginal = _dropOriginal
        self.typePercentage = typePercentage

    def fit(self, X, y, *_):
        original = pd.concat([y,X], axis=1)
        grouped = original.groupby([self.colname, self._target]).size()
        if self.typePercentage == 'totalTarget':
            df = grouped / original[self._target].sum()
        else:
            df = (grouped / grouped.groupby(level=0).sum())

        if self.typePercentage == 'totalTarget':
            nameCol = "pre_" + self.colname
        else:
            nameCol = "pre2_" + self.colname
        self.nameCol = nameCol
        grouped = df.reset_index(name=nameCol)
        groupedOnly = grouped[grouped[self._target] == 1]
        groupedOnly = groupedOnly.drop(self._target, 1)

        self.result =  groupedOnly
        return self

    def transform(self, dataF):
        mergedThing = pd.merge(dataF, self.result, on=self.colname, how='left')
        mergedThing.loc[(mergedThing[self.nameCol].isnull()), self.nameCol] = 0
        if self._dropOriginal:
            mergedThing = mergedThing.drop(self.colname, 1)
        return mergedThing
```

It would be used in a pipeline like this:

```
pipeline =  Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('continuous', Pipeline([
            ('extract', ColumnExtractor(CONTINUOUS_FIELDS)),
        ])),
        ('factors', Pipeline([
            ('extract', ColumnExtractor(FACTOR_FIELDS)),
            # using labelencoding and all bias
            ('bias',  PercentageAllTransformer(FACTOR_FIELDS, _dropOriginal=True, typePercentage='totalTarget')),
        ]))
    ], n_jobs=-1)),
    ('estimator', estimator)
])
```

The `pipeline` will be fitted with `X` and `y` where both are data frames. I am unsure of `X.as_matrix` would help.

Comment: `pandas` objects are wrappers around `numpy` objects. There is no `pandas` array, I believe you mean `Series`? Anyway, maybe your problem would be solved simply by returning `self.values` instead of `self`.

Comment: As for persistence, there are several ways to go about it. Generally, object serialization in Python will use the `pickle` module.

Comment: Indeed I meant pandas data frames. The point is if I understand it correctly: orignal `original.groupby([self.colname, self._target]`is no longer a dataframe but a numpy array e.g. the colnames do no longer work. so a self.values does not seem to be enough.

Comment: No, `groupby` returns a `groupby` object, which usually is used to generate a new `DataFrame`. You can't access `self.colname, self._target` as you normally would because by default, these are used as the `index` to the new `DataFrame`. Pass the `as_index=False` to `groupby` to retain your grouping columns as columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Converting Things Back and Forth

Pandas has a .to_records() method, and, as you mentioned, a .as_matrix() method. The .to_records() method will actually keep your column names for you. Numpy *does* support named columns in arrays. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).

- Persistence

Pandas has a pandas.to_pickle(obj, filename) method, which takes a pandas object and [pickles](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it. There is a corresponding pandas.read_pickle(filename) method.

Numpy has a [save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) function as well.